# Copying image always creates new image in landscape mode

Tags: android

I'm using the following line of code to copy an image taken within my app, however the new image that is created is always saved in landscape mode. The original image is in portrait.

```
Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),ImageFileName,     "Title1.jpg", null);
```

Can i change this line in someway to set the orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used the code below to determine the orientation and to rotate the image

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenImageName);

              try {
                  ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(takenImageName);
                  int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

                  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                  if (orientation == 6) {
                      matrix.postRotate(90);
                  }
                  else if (orientation == 3) {
                      matrix.postRotate(180);
                  }
                  else if (orientation == 8) {
                      matrix.postRotate(270);
                  }
                  imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
              }
              catch (Exception e) {

              }
```